# Behind the proxy setting in Jmeter cant recognize HostName :java.net.UnknownHostException error thrown

Tags: proxy, jmeter, settings, behind

I am working in a company which has a proxy to connect to internet and I want to do simple load test on www.google.com. So I tried to setup behind the proxy in Jmeter as below:

[image]

When I am trying to run the test it shows up below error. Can anyone help me out in this issue?

[image]

Comment: How about remove the protocol from your Proxy Server's input. In other word, replace `http://proxyconf.my-it-solutions.net/` to `proxyconf.my-it-solutions.net`. I guess "/" at the end of your host is also not needed.

Comment: Great! Resolved question should be closed in here. I will post the answer which is the same with comment, so please accept and close your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about remove the protocol from your Proxy Server's input.

In other word, replace `http://proxyconf.my-it-solutions.net/` to `proxyconf.my-it-solutions.net`.

I guess `/` at the end of your host is also not needed.